# Anchor tag href points to div after clicking it adds undefined in url

Tags: jquery, anchor, jquery-events, anchor-scroll

I have code like this:

```
<a href="#div-part" title="title">go to div part<a>
<form>
...
</form>
<div id="div-part">
<div>
```

After clicking the anchor tag scroll automatically moves to div part but instead of `#div-part` in url it adds `#undefined` in URL.
e.g. `localhost:80/index.jsp#undefined`.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you using any js code which might be affecting this behaviour?

Comment: `undefined` is not part of HTML, so you're obviously using something that you didn't post.

Comment: no js is invlolved in it. Plain HTML, I m clicking the anchor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution to scroll to particular div

```
$(function() {
    $('a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);       

    });
 });
```

[Check **DEMO** here.](http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/dY5Lj/)

Comment: Jeek,It work goods but adding this snippet will not add any content in URL. But I want corresponding div-part added in URL. Eg., http://locahost:80/index.jsp#div-part

Comment: @user3809019 : Okay, I got it, check my updated jsFiddle and code. I removed this line : `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: jQuery to solve what the OP said it's a purely html issue feels super bad.